# Alias to a class template with class template argument in C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I work in `C++17` and I need to create an alias like this:

```
template<const unsigned int x>
using AnotherClass_MyClass3 = MyClass<AnotherClass<x>, 3>;
```

so that later in the code I can call:

```
AnotherClass_MyClass3(arg);  // calls the constructor
```

But I get the following error:

```
test.cpp:1563:13: error: alias template 'AnotherClass_MyClass3' requires template arguments; argument deduction only allowed for class templates
```

How can I overcome this?

All this is because I need to write a partial specialisation for `MyClass` that would operate on `AnotherClass` instances, but the latter is a template too..
Sorry, if this is trivial, I am a relative beginner in C++.

Comment: As proposed, `AnotherClass_MyClass3` would _itself_ be a template that varies based on the value of `x`. So you'd need to do something like `AnotherClass_MyClass3<0>` to mean `MyClass<AnotherClass<0>, 3>`

Comment: But `template<typename T> using MyClass3 = MyClass<T, 3>;` works, despite being a template that varies... (this a an alias for `MyClass` instances on built-in types).

Comment: That's performing [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). The compiler is able to use the type of `arg` to deduce what the type of `T` is when you write `MyClass3(arg);`. (It's not always possible for it to do this, but it tries.) It's _not_ able to deduce what the value of the non-type template parameter `x` should be, though.

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand now.